# Having issue with "else if" in Java where need to have second example of text input by user to change data

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to use the "else if" function to have a second instance where if the first character of the input is, say "p", to change the full text to lower case using ".toLowerCase".

Am trying to just keep the one String, or should I need to set a second String to get this criteria to run.

Code currently is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a uncoded string: ");
    String first = input.nextLine();
    if (first.charAt(0) == 'u') {
        first = first.toUpperCase();{

        if (first.chatAt(0) == 'l') {
            first = first.toLowerCase();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + first);


}
}
```

}

The first part works to change text to upper case using "toUpperCase" but am having trouble getting to include the second itteration to run.

Get this error message in the Console:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method chatAt(int) is undefined for the type String

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there another String class in your project?

Comment: Not yet, but would assume it would have to be, as just would be a second criteria that would need to be met. Was trying to use "else if" just to move onto a second scenario.

Comment: You should definitely *not* have another String class. But if you did, it might explain the error you're seeing.

Comment: The error is due to mistyping of charAt(int). You wrote chatAt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have nested `if` statements instead of `else if`, where if the first letter is u, then you enter that block and check if the first letter is l. Keep in mind the code below will not work as you would like if the user enters strings such as "Unicorn".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a uncoded string: ");
    String first = input.nextLine();
    input.close();

    if (first.charAt(0) == 'u') {
      first = first.toUpperCase();
    } else if (first.charAt(0) == 'l') {
      first = first.toLowerCase();
    }

    System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + first);
  }
}
```

Also typically the [`if else`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) will be paired with an additional else afterwards to handle all other cases, like so:

```
if (condition){//Check one case
  // do something
} else if (condition){//Check another case
  // do something
} else { //All other cases
  // do something else
}
```